# Ubuntu tiled windows with linked visibility / size

Tags: window, window-manager

I rely heavily on Ubuntu's feature of being able to tile a window to the left/right half of the screen, either by dragging or with the use of keyboard shortcuts.

Recently, apparently Ubuntu shipped an update, so that now, if I have two tiled windows open (one to the left and one to the right), and I resize one of the twem --- the other resizes accordingly, so they both keep filling the screen. I find this immensely useful, and am very happy with this update.

For a while, a second feature seemed to have co-occured with it: when switching between windows (with alt-tab), the two would behave as if they were 'one' --- both appearing / disappearing together. Say I have them both on the foreground, and I switch to a maximixed Firefox, and then back to one of the two: them not just the one, but both, would re-appear on the foreground.

However, this second feature has now been disabled again. I have no idea where/when they came from, and why/when the second was removed again, but I'd love very much to have it back :D

**Does anybody know the names / origins of these features? And hw to bring back the second one?**

System specs:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- GNOME 3.28.1